# Custom tags in atom feed

Tags: xml, model-view-controller, symfony1, feed, atom-feed

I am using `Symfony` MVC to build a website. One of my model classes has two date fields: `start date` and `end date`. I want to provide this data via both web interface and atom feed. Should I make custom tags `<dateStart>` and `<dateEnd>` or should I add these to the `summary` tag? Or is there another solution? What are merits and demerits of these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should use Atom extension `<age:expires>` for the expiration date `end date` and use `<published>` for the `start date`

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-snell-atompub-feed-expires-06#page-4
http://www.atomenabled.org/developers/syndication/